# Site creation from template - Feature not activated error

Tags: 2013, permissions, site-collection, site-template

I have created a site collection in my testing environment and once i satisfied with it.

1. I created a template (worked fine)
2. Import to another site collection and tried to create a sub site with the template.

When I click OK to create a site it throws an error whose Screen shot is attached below. I have created many sub sites in the same site collection in my testing environment and it worked fine, this time I am trying to import to another site collection. I have not change any settings as well.     [image]

Close dialogProblem applying web template
This web template requires that certain features be installed, activated, and licensed. The following problems are blocking application of the template:

```
Feature Description Feature Scope   Feature ID  Problem
PSWApproval Feature Site collection ad739f9e-1525-4dec-a25e-10821ca70c95    Not activated
GlobalHold Feature  Site collection 2a6bf8e8-10b5-42f2-9d3e-267dfb0de8d4    Not activated
PWAWebParts Feature Site collection 10eb8dad-31aa-4461-9843-27305d0c7c93    Not activated
PwaIdeaList Feature Site collection ce0143de-6894-428b-9f6b-37bd6848ec26    Not activated
PWARibbon Feature   Site collection 1d253548-c70d-40fd-9930-9d313bedc359    Not activated
MobileExcelWebAccess Feature    Site collection e995e28b-9ba8-4668-9933-cf5c146d7a9f    Not activated
This template can't be used for this site collection until the issues above are resolved.
```

Answer (score 0):

when taking a template of a sub site make sure the new location has exactly the same site collections features active at the root level!

its saying at the time when you took the template of the subsite you had 6 features enabled.

where you are adding this new site template it looks like those 6 features either don't exist or are not enabled at the site collection level. Are you sure its under the same site collection level or a new web application?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are on SharePoint online or Office 365?
Normally the suggested answer above would be sufficient on premises, as the Site collection features are available to you more easily, and do not change - either go to Site settings at the  Site collection level, or by activating the features with Powershell if they are hidden features.

However, in the new online world Microsoft are releasing new or enhanced features all the time, and even if you create a new site collection (to create some nice customised templates, for eg) it might look like the site collection has no extra features enabled, but it could have some extra, just by being a newer site collection.

I suggest to get around this you will need to enable these hidden features using PowerShell, or deactivate and activate the Site collection feature that the new piece is part of (- thanks MS, this option is all guesswork).

The following article will help if you need those PowerShell commands for Online.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863609/sharepoint-2013-mobileexcelwebaccess-feature-missing-when-creating-subsite-using

Answer (score 0):

If feature is hidden:

> Download and install: Powershell ISE:
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45885
>
> Download and install: SharePoint online client components SDK:
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038
>
> Modify the attached scripts Required Parameters for your SharePoint and the
> feature code found in the error code you are receiving:

```
#Required Parameters 
$sSiteColUrl = "https://portal.sharepoint.com"
$sUserName = "admin@portal.com"  
$sFeatureGuid="2a6bf8e8-10b5-42f2-9d3e-267dfb0de8d4" 
$sPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your password: " -AsSecureString
```

Run the powershell ISE as Administrator
Run script

```
#Script that enables a feature in a SPO Site 
# Required Parameters: 
#  -> $sUserName: User Name to connect to the SharePoint Online Site Collection. 
#  -> $sPassword: Password for the user. 
#  -> $sSiteColUrl: SharePoint Online Site Collection 
#  -> $sFeatureGuid: GUID of the feature to be enabled 
    
     
    $host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread" 
     
    #Definition of the function that allows to enable a SPO Feature 
    function Enable-SPOFeature 
    { 
        param ($sSiteColUrl,$sUserName,$sPassword,$sFeatureGuid) 
        try 
        {     
            #Adding the Client OM Assemblies         
            Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
            Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
     
            #SPO Client Object Model Context 
            $spoCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($sSiteColUrl)  
            $spoCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($sUsername, $sPassword)   
            $spoCtx.Credentials = $spoCredentials       
     
            Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------"  -foregroundcolor Green 
            Write-Host "Enabling the Feature with GUID $sFeatureGuid !!" -ForegroundColor Green 
            Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------"  -foregroundcolor Green 
     
            $guiFeatureGuid = [System.Guid] $sFeatureGuid 
            #############################################
            # todo: change object: $spoSite=$spoCtx.Site | $spoSite=$spoCtx.Web
            $spoSite=$spoCtx.Site 
    
            # todo: change scope: [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None | Farm | Site | Web
            # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.featuredefinitionscope.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
            $spoSite.Features.Add($sFeatureGuid, $true, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None) 
            #############################################
    
            $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery() 
            $spoCtx.Dispose() 
        } 
        catch [System.Exception] 
        { 
            write-host -f red $_.Exception.ToString()    
        }     
    } 
     
    #Required Parameters 
    $sSiteColUrl = "https://portal.sharepoint.com" 
    $sUserName = "admin@portal.com" 
    $sFeatureGuid= " e995e28b-9ba8-4668-9933-cf5c146d7a9f"
    $sPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your password: " -AsSecureString  
     
    Enable-SPOFeature -sSiteColUrl $sSiteColUrl -sUserName $sUserName -sPassword $sPassword -sFeatureGuid $sFeatureGuid
```

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/MobileExcelWebAccess-Feature-Site-Template-Error/td-p/2531