# Creating a new subsite from a template and sharepoint says "PSWApproval, PWAWebParts,PwaIdeaList not activated" and does not create the subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template

I'm creating a new subsite from a template I've imported from another site.  It won't import as I get the message below.  How do i solve this problem?

> Feature Description   Feature Scope   Feature ID  Problem PSWApproval
>   Feature   Site collection ad739f9e-1525-4dec-a25e-10821ca70c95    Not
>   activated PWAWebParts Feature Site
>   collection    10eb8dad-31aa-4461-9843-27305d0c7c93    Not activated
>   PwaIdeaList Feature   Site
>   collection    ce0143de-6894-428b-9f6b-37bd6848ec26    Not activated

Thanks

Comment: are you using Project Server ?

Answer (score 0):

You have created a template from a site in a site collection that uses project server features. The site collection where you used the template does not have the features enabled.

Enable them in the site collection where you would like to use the template and your template should work, but you should consider if it's a good idea to enable those features in the specific site collection.

What you could do is to create a new site collection, enable the project server features there, and then restore your template there or create a subsite. Then you can deactivate the project feature and create a new template. Now the template won't require the features above and it should work in your first site collection.

[Creating a subsite through Template gave me an error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192983/creating-a-subsite-through-template-gave-me-an-error)